# How to pass user data to a callback function

Tags: c, callback, raku, nativecall

I'm working on a NativeCall interface; there's a C function which accepts a callback, defined as:

```
typedef void (* ExifContentForeachEntryFunc) (ExifEntry *, void *user_data);
void exif_content_foreach_entry (ExifContent *content, ExifContentForeachEntryFunc func, void *user_data);
```

My first take has been:

```
sub exif_content_foreach_entry(ExifContent $exifcontent, &func (ExifEntry $entry, Buf $data), Buf $user_data) is native(LIB) is export { * }
```

but when invoked this function generates an error:

```
Internal error: unhandled dyncall callback argument type
  in method CALL-ME at /opt/rakudo-pkg/share/perl6/sources/24DD121B5B4774C04A7084827BFAD92199756E03 (NativeCall) line 588
```

If I ignore the user_data argument, everything works, so the rest of the declaration is fine: I just don't get to pass any additional data to the callback function.

On other occasions I used a Buf to pass a block of (possibly) binary data to a C function and it worked; the difference here is the callback function.
Any idea how to solve this problem?

(using perl6 2018.03)

Comment: @raiph I don't know why I got that impression. Noted and changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how to pass a `Buf` as user data since `Buf` is not a native type. But you could use for instance a `CStruct` instead:

```
class UserData is repr('CStruct') {
    has int32 $.dummy;
}
```

Then the declaration would be:

```
sub exif_content_foreach_entry(
    ExifContent $exifcontent, 
    &func (ExifEntry $entry, UserData $data),
    UserData $user_data) is native(LIB) is export { * }
```

And the callback can be declared and defined as for example:

```
sub my-callback (ExifEntry $entry, UserData $data) {
    say "In callback";
    say "Value of data: ", $data.dummy;
}
```

**Edit**:

Here is a workaround to pass a Perl 6 type like `Buf` (i.e not a native type) to the callback using a closure. For example:

```
my $buf = Buf.new( 1, 2, 3);
my $callback = my sub (ExifEntry $entry, UserData $data) {
    my-callback( $entry, $buf);
}
```

Then declare the real callback `my-callback` like this:

```
sub my-callback (ExifEntry $entry, Buf $data) {
    say "In callback";
    say "Value of data: ", $data;
}
```

And call the library function like this:

```
exif_content_foreach_entry( $content, &$callback, $data );
```

Comment: Your solution works using an int32, but I wanted to allow the module users to pass any kind of data, so I prefer something like a Buf or Blob.
Elsewhere I successfully used a Buf when the C declaration type was a void *, hence that was the first thing I tried here.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question and you've probably implemented workarounds long ago, but in the interest of catching others with a similar issue, I'll post my answer now.

I've had to do this several times for different `NativeCall` library interfaces, so I decided to package it up into a [NativeHelpers::Callback](https://github.com/CurtTilmes/perl6-nativehelpers-callback) module.

It provides some simple methods to associate a perl object with an `CPointer` and easily look it up from within a callback function.

This is all untested, but something like this should work for your case:

```
use NativeHelpers::Callback :cb;                                                

class ExifEntry is repr('CPointer') { ... }                                     

sub exif_content_foreach_entry(ExifContent $exifcontent,                        
    &func (ExifEntry $entry, int64), int64) is native(LIB) is export { * }      

class MyPerlObject {                                                            
    has $.entry;                                                                
    has Buf $.buf;                                                              
    ...                                                                         
}                                                                               

sub MyCallBack(ExifEntry $entry, int64 $id) {                                   
    my MyPerlObject $object = cb.lookup($id);
    ... do stuff with $object ...                                   
}                                                                               

my ExifEntry $entry = ...;                                                      

my MyPerlObject $object = MyPerlObject.new(:$entry, buf => ...);                
cb.store($object, $entry);                                                      
exif_content_foreach_entry($exifcontent, &MyCallBack, cb.id($entry));
```

Comment: Interesting module! Though in my case what I have to pass along is a Perl6 Str, not a native value, so if I have understood it right, I can't use your module.

Comment: That should be fine -- Just `cb.store()` the Str associated with your C object pointer, then register the callback with the `cb.id()` of that pointer.  Then call `cb.lookup()` in the callback and it will return the Str.

Comment: In my case I have no C object pointer: the C function I call has three arguments: a first argument which will be scanned internally, a callback function which is called when the scanner finds something and an additional pointer. The function will pass that pointer "as is" to the callback. I want to pass a Str variable to the function, which in turn will pass it to the callback. [continues]

Comment: `cb.store()` expects two arguments, but I have just one Str variable; if I try something like `cb.store($var, $var)` I get an error: `Native call expected return type with CPointer, CStruct, CArray, or VMArray representation, but got a P6opaque (Str)`. It comes from the `cb.id()` method invoked by `cb.store()` which tries to call `nativecast(int64, $thing)` passing along the Str.

Comment: Hmm.. I've always got some C thing I want to associate the callback with.  Then within the callback, it uses that thing to find the data.  Usually something I associate with a Perl CStruct or CPointer, some sort of handle that the callback gets to tell apart multiple instances.